# Scroll View not scrolling in react native

Tags: react-native

Scroll view not scrolling

Example that I'm trying on Expo:

```
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in Android other **touchable** steals user’s *touch event* that's why you can not scroll the ScrollView but many times it works as expected on IOS platform. I guess you just need to add `onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}` to the View which wraps the intended ScrollView. Can you please try below code:

```
   <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
          <Item />
          <Item />
          <Item />
          <Item />
          <Item />
          <Item />
        </View>

      </ScrollView>
   </View>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add flex: 1 on ScrollView

If doesnt work you can try make something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native</Text>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native</Text>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native</Text>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native</Text>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native</Text>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native</Text>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native</Text>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native</Text>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  welcome: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    margin: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    paddingTop: 70,
  }
});
```

Comment: Scroll works with this code, but when I change `flexDirection` to `row` and `wrap` views, the scroll breaks

Comment: This doesn't really work for me. Could you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ScrollView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
            <Item />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
```

If the content total height is greater than the scroll view, then only the scroll view will scroll.